# org.hibernate.AssertionFailure during criteria.uniqueResult

Tags: java, hibernate

I am selecting data from a table which is call pHistory, this table does not have any relationShip with CenterLog entity, however, I am still getting hibernate error complain that null id in CenterLog entity.

The log is as follow:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.audit.entity.CenterLog entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:996) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1589) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:328) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
```

As my understanding, uniqueResult is not doing any save event, but not sure I am still hitting this.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says `(don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)`: there was another exception earlier and it the cause of the problem.

You need to find that other exception and fix it.

Comment: Didnt see any exception happen before this exception. what direction i can continue look further to debug?

Comment: `null id in com.audit.entity.CenterLog entry` why would a CenterLog object have no ID? Are you trying to save one?